# Is it possible to get permissions of any app in Google Play Store before downloading?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am a beginner programmer in android and I want to create the application that can get permissions of any application in google play store using android studio. I have noticed that there is an api called android-market-api. However, it doesn't work for me anyway.
Here is the code.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    String android_id = Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    MarketSession session = new MarketSession();
    session.login("myusername", "pwd");
    session.getContext().setAndroidId(android_id);
}
```

And it error at this line.

```
 MarketSession session = new MarketSession();
```

I am not sure that this api still working or not, so if there is a suggest or a better way to achieve my goal.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well you need to add permissions in the manifest.

Comment: There is no public api  for this purpose available
https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/
It states the following "
The Google Play Developer API allows you to perform a number of publishing and app-management tasks...". Another words you can use api for publishing and  management of your OWN APP